# How to change large text default factor scaling Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, text, scaling

How can I change large text (in universal access) default factor scaling from 1.25 to 1.21 in Ubuntu 18.04?

Thanks,
Diego

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install "Tweaks" from the software center. On the "Fonts" tab, you can set your desired the scaling factor precisely.

You may also set the scaling factor with a terminal command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.21
```

Reset to the system default setting with the command

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor
```

Comment: This does not answer the user's question. He's not asking how to change the scaling factor he's asking how to change the scaling factor that the universal access applet enabled when you switch "Large Text" on in that applet.

Comment: @Jonathan Kamens, I guess the user was more interested in the actual font size than in the universal access applet, since the answer was accepted. But you are right, the problem was, in the body of the question, somewhat formulated as an XY problem: In reality I want to solve problem X (change my font scale) but instead I am asking about problem Y (how to modify a provided tool to change font scale).